# firebase quota exceeded (per day?)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsDailyNonbillable' and limit 'CPU allocation in function invocations per day' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:221474907579'., Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsNonbillable' and limit 'CPU allocation in function invocations per day' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:221474907579'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in your project at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=samsungmap-xyz. Function cannot be executed.

my project still runs fine if i use firebase serve --only functions
but on deployment it shows the above error
It mentions somewhere "per day limit".
Does that mean i can deploy after 24 hrs and quota will reset or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to deploy whenever you want.  The functions just won't run until the daily quota resets.